# Pass php variable with sql data to new php file with link

Tags: php, variables, url, blogs

I have a blog setup where journal.php shows snippets of the blogs in the database. It creates a link so that when clicked should open blog.php and show the full blog and comments section. I can't figure out how to get the link in journal.php to open the id of the blog selected, then pass that to blog.php and show that blog.

journal.php

```
<?php   // retreive post
     include('php/config.php');
    include ('php/function.php');
    dbConnect();

    $blog_query = mysql_query(
    'SELECT * 
    FROM Blog
    ORDER BY DATE DESC');


    function getIntro($str, $count = 200, $id=1) { 
        return preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr(nl2br($str), 0, 
$count)) . '<a href="blog.php?page=' . $ID . '">Read more...</a>';
        }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($blog_query)):

    $date = date_create($row['DATE']);
    $str = $row['CONTENT'];
    $ID = $row['ID'];


        $new_string = getIntro($str);
    ?>

    <div class="post">
        <h2><?php echo $row['TITLE']?></h2>
        <h3><?php echo date_format($date, 'l, F j, Y')?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $new_string?></p>
    </div>

</div>      
<?php endwhile ?>
```

Blog.php

```
<?php

    include('php/config.php');
    include ('php/function.php');               
    $_GET[$ID]; //Get ID from link in journal.php
    dbConnect();

    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Blog WHERE ID = '$ID'") or die(mysql_error()); 

    $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ); 

    $BID = $info['ID'];
    $date = date_create($info['DATE']);

     ?>

    <div class="post">
        <h2><?php echo $info['TITLE']?></h2>
        <h3><?php echo date_format($date, 'l, F j, Y')?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $info['CONTENT']?></p>

    <h2>Comments.....</h2>
    <div class="comment-block">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In blog.php change `$_GET[$ID];` to `$ID = $_GET['page'];`

Also, change:

```
function getIntro($str, $count = 200, $id=1) {
```

to:

```
function getIntro($str, $count = 200, $ID=1) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That didn't change anything. If it's worth anything, even when I hover over the "read more" link on journal.php, the link in the browser shows blog.php?page= wihout the id number as I expected.

Comment: I just edited my answer. Looks like you use lowercase $id as an argument and uppercase $ID inside the function. PHP is case sensitive.

Comment: so, that worked, but I am still an idiot. So in the getIntro function I set $ID=1 when I need $ID to equal the blog ID. Arrgghhh, learning is frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ID = $_GET['page'];
```

so you can use `$ID` in query

Comment: so, that worked, but I am still an idiot. So in the getIntro function I set $ID=1 when I need $ID to equal the blog ID. Arrgghhh, learning is frustrating!

Comment: @user3758073 PHP is a very easy language. when you are coding make check after each step to be sure that everything goes right. 1- test your query in phpMyAdmin . 2- get variable from database in PHP with simple query. if everything is good then creating your functions and all that stuff .. Good Luck